# Monitor socket with ngrep or perl for activity, then issue command

Tags: ruby, perl, grep, sockets, ngrep

I'd like to use ngrep and/or perl to monitor the incoming data stream on a socket, then, when the appropriate characters arrive, like in this case, the string "192.168.1.101:8080", input to the data stream a redirect to another ipaddress, such as "192.168.1.102"

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, thats possible.

Algorithm/application would require:

- MiM listenning server (creating sockets session sockets)
- hand-shake on MiM:
- (best thing would be if there would be a text stream not binary protocol used)
- recv from client, parse message then:
- if IP comes in, open or use already opened socket to the target server/port
- send message or rest of the message to target server
- provide communication beteween client and target sever (operate as gateway)
- recv() client or server and send() back to appropriate side

General advice:
operate on select() or epoll(), approach more advanced but better.

Answer (score 0):

This can done easily in Perl.

Take a look at [perldoc perlipc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc.html), [IO::Socket](http://perldoc.perl.org/IO/Socket.html) and [IO::Select](http://perldoc.perl.org/IO/Select.html) for examples.

You might find [Beej's Guide to Network Programming](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/index.html) helpful, too.  The examples are all in C, but Perl's networking API is pretty close to the C flavor.